# QGIS procedure for Multidirectional, oblique-weighted, shaded-relief?

Tags: qgis, hillshade, shaded-relief

Is QGIS capable of the multidirectional, oblique-weighted,shaded-relief method described at  http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1992/of92-422/of92-422.pdf ?  If so, what are the steps necessary in QGIS to achieve this style of hillshading?

I am able to utilize the hillshade tool in QGIS 2.6 to obtain a "single-directional" hillshade image from 1/3 arc NED data, but I'm interested in the method described in the link.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS3 has a plugin (Batch Hillshader) to generate a three light exposure hillshade. The webpage is here: https://github.com/PANOimagen/batch_hillshader. It's in the official QGIS Plugins Repository.